# What is wrong with this Dockerfile statement? Which one should I use?

Tags: docker

If I want to run, for example wget, in a Docker file, I can type this:

```
RUN wget http://example.com
```

If I want do an `echo` command I could do this

```
RUN echo 'Hello' >> /home/file.text
```

But I've also seen this:

```
RUN bash -c 'echo $USERNAME:ros | chpasswd'
```

If I want to run a shell script, I could do this

```
RUN 'bash ./install_foo.sh'
```

I also was recommended this:

```
RUN . /home/ros/.bashrc
```

I think there are some invalid examples above and others that have subtle differing semantics. I would like to

1. Understand it so I can learn
2. What the right one is to use when I want to run a shell script

Comment: What do you want to *do*?

Comment: Probably `curl -o output_filename http://example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brain dump of related one-line answers:

- Every `RUN` command launches a new shell (in a new container even) with a new clean environment and doesn't read any dotfiles.  `RUN export ...` and `RUN . ...` are both no-ops that will have no effect on later steps.
- Many standard Docker paths (like `docker run ... some command`) don't involve a shell at all, so if you create a `.bashrc` or `.profile` file it will be ignored in many common cases.
- Unquoted `RUN some command`, `CMD some command`, and `ENTRYPOINT some command` are all [automatically wrapped in `sh -c '...'`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) and you basically never need to say this explicitly.  (In the case of `ENTRYPOINT` using the unquoted form is probably a bug.)  Forms like `CMD ["some", "command"]` do not implicitly involve a shell (and don't expand environment variables).
- GNU bash has several vendor extensions that unfortunately are in widespread use; Alpine base images don't include bash.  In particular never say `source` when `.` is in the standard and does the same thing.
- If you're installing software in an image, your best choice is to install it in a "system" location (`pip install` without an active virtual environment, `npm install -g`, `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`); if you must install it somewhere else, use the Dockerfile `ENV` directive to set any environment variables that are needed; and if you can't do that, an `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper script can programmatically set the environment for the main process (but not any `docker exec` shells).
- Just in general, `./foo.sh` will run a shell script (provided it is executable and starts with a `#!/bin/sh` line); `bash foo.sh` will as well (but doesn't require it to be executable and explicitly specifies which shell to use); and `. ./foo.sh` runs it *in the context of the current shell* (only this form can change environment variables for example).